# Extract unique two digits and place unique non-duplicate two digits in immediate next column separated by pipeline

Tags: excel, split, duplicates, pipeline

I have similar inputs in 1000 cells of column A wherein each value has first two characters  are followed by some numbers and there are multiple pipeline separated values as shown below -

**Input (column A)**

**Cell A1 =** US6690414B2 | US420416T | CN1256694C | CN1401109A | DE60137365D1

**Cell A2 =** EP1346328A1 | EP1346328B1 | ES2320416T3 | JP2004516556A

**Cell A3 =** US20020071032A1 | NZ2002048970A1

**Desired Output**

**Cell B1 =** US | CN | DE

**Cell B2 =** EP | ES | JP

**Cell B3 =** US | NZ

PS - I have checked all similar questions but this is not answered before, therefore asking. Thanks in advance.

Used this code

```
Sub main2()
    Dim strng As Variant

    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For Each cell In Columns(1),SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) ... Next cell
        For Each strng In Split(Replace(cell, " ", ""), "|")
            .Item(Left(strng, 2)) = .Item(Left(strng, 2)) & "|" & strng & "|"
        Next
        Range("B1").Resize(,.count).Value = ".Items"
        With cell.Offset(,1).Resize(.Count)
            .Replace "||", "--"
            .Replace "|", ""
            .Replace "--", " | "
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This will require vba, what have you tried?  Please show the attempts to code a resolution and explain the error you are finding.  Stack Overflow is not a code for me site.

Comment: Sub main2()
    Dim strng As Variant

    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        For Each strng In Split(Replace(Range("A1"), " ", ""), "|")
            .Item(Left(strng, 2)) = .Item(Left(strng, 2)) & "|" & strng & "|"
        Next
        Range("A2").Resize(.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(.Items)
        With Range("A2").Resize(.Count)
            .Replace "||", "--"
            .Replace "|", ""
            .Replace "--", " | "
        End With
    End With
End Sub

Comment: I have tried this

Comment: Please [edit] the original post and insert the code along with a explanation of what errors.  do not put code in the comments.